# URL uncommon redirection

Tags: url, redirect

We have a WordPress website with URL http://smartwavestudios.com/ when you open the URL it redirects properly but when I type http://www.smartwavestudios.com/ it redirects to other page. how come the URL with no "www" is different from that with "www"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that DNS servers are not returning the same thing for your www site and your non-www site. While this is usually fixed with time, i.e. wait a few days, you can also just add the following to your .htaccess file to fix the issue.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```